# How to collect and move data from a Json link to pandas Dataframe using request

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a link as below:

> https://iislliveblob.niftyindices.com/jsonfiles/Heatmap/FinalHeatMapNIFTY%20BANK.json?_=1566641233858

I want to collect and move table data from a link to pandas Dataframe using request

Comment: show your code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is simpler than using [`pd.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) routine for such case?

```
In [2]: pd.read_json('https://iislliveblob.niftyindices.com/jsonfiles/Heatmap/FinalHeatMapNIFTY%20BANK.json?_=15
   ...: 66641233858')                                                                                           
Out[2]: 
    Indexmcap_today  Indexmcap_yst  NewIndexValue  ...  sharesOutstanding      symbol                   time
0      185787484706   185096824912   27035.620450  ...         1986792096  FEDERALBNK  Aug 23, 2019 16:00:00
1       94015024217    92934391755   27036.436029  ...         4782477126  IDFCFIRSTB  Aug 23, 2019 16:00:00
2      170122910956   167793447043   27039.047804  ...          427318817     RBLBANK  Aug 23, 2019 16:00:00
3       78039629610    75401497477   27039.693345  ...         4604047028         PNB  Aug 23, 2019 16:00:00
4      129197826454   125259710888   27042.412097  ...         3846727356  BANKBARODA  Aug 23, 2019 16:00:00
5      127258599093   120922516944   27047.427144  ...         2316958738     YESBANK  Aug 23, 2019 16:00:00
6     1571596601509  1565086749643   27047.790562  ...         2619107432    AXISBANK  Aug 23, 2019 16:00:00
7     1205529358622  1194190000951   27057.890868  ...         8924611534        SBIN  Aug 23, 2019 16:00:00
8     2443146242739  2466008258667   26986.362979  ...         6451364340   ICICIBANK  Aug 23, 2019 16:00:00
9     4183387487538  4205438912774   26988.058228  ...         2732812271    HDFCBANK  Aug 23, 2019 16:00:00
10     820545888847   836293106783   27001.242688  ...          692756723  INDUSINDBK  Aug 23, 2019 16:00:00
11    1881780775065  1892084363175   27012.627358  ...         1909120492   KOTAKBANK  Aug 23, 2019 16:00:00

[12 rows x 24 columns]
```